# A getter I made in vuex store.js is getting errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am using vuejs, vuex, and vuetify.

There are 3 files involved I will post the important parts.

Basically I want to display data corresponding to the route parameter.
Whenever I use the following in my Product.vue

```
<h1 class="heading primary--text"> {{ product.partNumber }}</h1>
```

Nothing on that file loads, and when I check the console I get the following...

Chrome: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Firefox: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: state.loadedProducts is undefined"

In this same project I made a vue page that loads all the products on the page using v-for, and one of the getters, just fine.

I am really unsure what is wrong, please help before my hairline disappears.

store.js

```
   getters:{
    loadedProducts (state) {
      return state.products.sort((productA, productB) => {
        return productA.partNumber > productB.partNumber
      })
    },
    loadedProduct (state) {
      return (productId) => {
        return state.loadedProducts.find((product) => {
          return product.partNumber === productId
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

router.js

```
 {
  path: '/product/:id',
  name: 'Product',
  props: true,
  component: Product
  }
```

Product.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Product',
  props: ['id'],
  computed: {
    product () {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedProduct(this.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to access the `loadedProducts` via `store`, instead access it through the getters themselves. The docs on [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access) provide an example of accessing other getters within a getter via the second argument.

> Getters will also receive other getters as the 2nd argument

```
loadedProduct (state, getters) {
  return (productId) => {
    return getters.loadedProducts.find((product) => {
      return product.partNumber === productId
    })
  }
}
```

Be sure you are setting reasonable defaults for your store properties such as an empty array for `products`.

Hopefully that helps!